# Does money function like a systemic form of energy?

Tags: macroeconomics, money

First let me say that I'm an MD with a background in science, not economics.

Recently, physicist Geoffrey West discovered that the same allometric scaling laws that have been known about in biology since the 1930's also appear in cities. These scaling laws have to do with energy distribution in systems with endpoints of a similar size. In the case of animals, that endpoint is the average cell in the system. In the case of cities, that endpoint is the average human in the system.

When I consider money in this context, it shares many peculiar properties with energy. Just like energy, money can be stored, spent, and converted into other forms of energy. Also, double entry accounting essentially implies the conservation of energy (the 1st law of thermodynamics). Also, insulin levels appear to set individual cellular access to the availability of systemic glucose (energy) in a similar manner to the federal reserve rate and the availability of credit to the average consumer.

Since all living systems can be considered thermodynamically open, entropy-reducing flow networks, I am curious if a more general physics of living systems is emerging that can apply from cells up to civilization?

If humans are creating an emergent meta-organism that functions on scalable metabolic principles, shouldn't these inform our understanding of human economic systems and, if so, does money function like a systemic form of energy?

Comment: What % of similarity constitutes "functioning like". Without you specifying that this is unanswerable. Before I became economists I used to study astrophysics and first law of thermodynamics is terrible example, money can be both created and destroyed within the economic system. So that is actually example of money not being like energy in physics since in physics energy cannot be created or destroyed in closed system but money can.

Comment: All living systems are thermodynamically open. Double entry accounting applies at the microeconomic scale and, there, money (energy) is conserved. At the systemic level, however, money can be created and destroyed and this amounts to a change in the nominal but not real value represented by money. In addition, insulin insensitivity in diabetic patients would correspond to such an inflationary (or deflationary as the case may be) condition. In the diabetic, it literally takes more insulin molecules to produce the same cellular uptake of glucose.

Comment: In the animal system, glucose isn't energy *itself* but merely a form of energy for that systemic level. Within the cell, the fundamental currency of energy is ATP, not glucose. At every level of biological organization, there appears to be a fundamental currency that establishes how that system manages its metabolic demands. Especially given recent physical discoveries, to me, this seems indistinguishable from economics at the human scale.

Comment: 1. no double entry accounting can be used on macro scale as well 2. Money can be destroyed even at a single company scale even though it cannot created (unless we talk about a bank), anyone can just take pile of cash and burn it. 3. Money do not represent real value, money is inartistically worthless. 4. Also the real value (goods and services) in economy can be destroyed or created at both micro and macro scale. The thermodynamic analogy simply does not work. 5. Also by the way double entry accounting allows for creation of new money and destruction.

Comment: Also double entry accounting allows for creation and destruction of money. When central bank creates new money ex nihilo it uses double entry accounting when they create money ,on asset side they record reserves and on liability side there is account for money in circulation. Double entry accounting is bad analogy for how thermodynamics works

Comment: "Double entry accounting is bad analogy for how thermodynamics works." Maybe not all thermodynamics but, at least regarding the first law of thermodynamics, this is incorrect. Double entry accounting requires that every entry to an account requires a corresponding and opposite entry to a different account. In any physical system, energy is always conserved, meaning that any change in one form of energy requires a corresponding and opposite change in a different form of energy. The correspondence here is identical. The average person cannot create money.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140094/discussion-between-asklepian-and-1muflon1).

Comment: but double entry accounting allows even on a micro scale of a single company for 2 accounts to be created out of nothing. That’s not conservation of energy… can energy be created out of nothing on micro scale let’s say in the lab? The only way how it’s similar is that both first law and double energy accounting can be described by equation and that’s very bad analogy because lot of stuff can be represented by an equation. That’s like saying that perfectly competitive firm is analogy for thermodynamics because rational perfectly competitive firm would always choose prices to be equal

Comment: To marginal costs (P=MC) and then say this is analogy for thermodynamics just because two things are equal. This way you can find analogue to thermodynamics everywhere but that’s very weak analogy

Comment: ok we can continue in chat